# While Loop Works with || but not &&, Not Understanding Why?

Tags: c#, loops, random, while-loop

The program's goal is to roll two dice until both of them equal 6. When I used && in the while statement it stops after one dice equals 6. Why is that? Shouldn't && test the first condition then if it is correct test the second?

```
while ((diceOne != 6) || (diceTwo != 6)) {
    diceOne = numberGeneration.Next(1, 7);
    diceTwo = numberGeneration.Next(1, 7);
    attempt = ++attempt;

    Console.WriteLine("Your first dice is: " + diceOne + " your second dice is: " + diceTwo);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any button to continue");
    Console.ReadKey();

}

Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempt);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 10):

It stops because you break the condition of one dice being different from 6.

```
while ((diceOne != 6) && (diceTwo != 6))
```

While will execute while both conditions are true.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Pedro, also you can use `break` statement in the `while(true)` loop and stop the loop when both of dices are equal to 6:

```
while (true) {
    diceOne = numberGeneration.Next(1, 7);
    diceTwo = numberGeneration.Next(1, 7);
    attempt = ++attempt;

    Console.WriteLine("Your first dice is: " + diceOne + " your second dice is: " + diceTwo);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any button to continue");
    Console.ReadKey();
    if (diceOne == 6 && diceTwo == 6) break;

}

Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempt);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the while loop condition is the *necessary and sufficient* condition to *continue* the loop. `(diceOne != 6) && (diceTwo != 6))` says that "both dice are not 6". When both dice are not 6, you certainly want to continue the loop, so it's a sufficient condition, but this is not a necessary condition. When else would you want to continue the loop? When one dice is 6 and one dice isn't!

The necessary and sufficient condition to continue the loop is that at least one dice is not 6, which is what the `||` expresses.

Answer (score 0):

Other users already have explained you why it's not working. I may suggest to modify the while statement like this:

```
while (!(diceOne == 6 && diceTwo == 6))
```

Comment: The question *is* why, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You are right, like i said in my answer the question has  already been answered by other users. My example could anyway be useful to OP because (and that's my humble opinion) is a more straightforward way to write the condition in the correct way.